# Two different CCMoveTo animation distances but with the same speed?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm scrolling a CCLabelBMFont from right to center, and then from center to left.  I am trying to make it so that the speed of the scrollng is the same between the two CCMoveTo animations.

Here is my code:

```
@interface ScrollableText : CCLabelBMFont
@end

@implementation ScrollableText

-(instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.scale       = 0.75f;
        self.fntFile     = MY_FONT;
        self.alignment   = kCCTextAlignmentLeft;
        self.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f, 0.5f);
        self.string      = string;
        self.visible     = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)scrollLeft {
    [self scrollWithStart:[self offScreenRightXPos]
                   middle:[self centerXPos]
                   finish:[self offScreenLeftXPos]];
}

-(void)scrollWithStart:(CGPoint)start
                middle:(CGPoint)middle
                finish:(CGPoint)finish {
    self.position = start;
    self.visible = YES;

    ccTime duration1 = [self durationForStart:start end:middle];
    ccTime duration2 = [self durationForStart:middle end:finish];

    CCSequence *actions = [CCSequence actions:
                           [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration1
                                               position:middle],
                           [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1],
                           [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration2
                                               position:finish]
                        , nil];
    [self runAction:actions];
}

-(ccTime)durationForStart:(CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end {
    CGFloat speed = 600.0f;
    ccTime duration;
    CGFloat distance = ccpDistance(start, end);
    return distance / speed;
}

-(CGPoint)offScreenLeftXPos {
    return ccp(-[self scaledContentWidth], 0);
}

-(CGPoint)centerXPos {
    return ccp(((self.parent.contentSize.width - [self scaledContentWidth]) / 2), 0);
}

-(CGPoint)offScreenRightXPos {
    return ccp(self.parent.contentSize.width, 0);
}

-(CGFloat)scaledContentWidth {
    return self.contentSize.width * self.scale;
}

@end
```

The problem I am having is, the speeds do not match.  The move from offScreenRightXPos to centerXPos is dramatically faster than the centerXPOs to the offScreenLeftXPos move...  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Have yo checked centerXPos is coming correctly as expected.
2. offScreenLeftXPos taking -width. It should be 0 right.

Comment: yes, the centerXPos value is right...  offScreenLeftXPos should be -scaledContentWidth.  0 would just be left aligned in the parent container.

Comment: Have you checked, if maybe the parent is also scaled?

Comment: @pmpod - no it's not...

Comment: Would the anchor pt of ccp(0.0f, 0.5f) be causing a mis-calculation in your distances?  Have you assumed somewhere that the label is actually centred over the x coord?  straw->grasp

Answer (score 0):

The animation is being affected by only two possible variables: the distance or the time, since you set the speed at 600.0f, so either the duration or the distance is causing the issue.

I'm sure you have stepped through your code, but if the label is moving from offscreen, pausing in the middle, and then moving offscreen again, then the distance is the same, and hence the time taken to move it must also be equal.

Have you checked that duration1 == duration2?

If duration1 == duration2, then the other culprit could be that in the same timeframe, the label is travelling different distances, and hence is actually not moving at the same speed.  Based on your code above, tho, that doesn't look possible.  The only thing I can think of is it being due to your anchor point not being the centre of your label...  perhaps your boundary cases are skewing your animation to the right, causing the distances to be different despite wanting it to be even down the middle.

Comment: duration1 does not equal duration2, and with the anchor point being at (0, 0.5) that means the distances cannot possibly be the same.  If the anchor point is changed to be (0.5, 0.5), then the distances would be the same, so I will try that.

Comment: oh, so centerXPos centers the label in the parent container, which does not mean centre of the actual screen, but actually a clipped window?  gotcha.  still, if you are centering it in the container, you can have it so duration1 equals duration2 and just have the label move from further outside the clipped area, regardless of anchoring.  I would try that first if you are really stumped on this one.

Comment: Yeah--- this problem really made no sense.  Anyway, I changed CCMoveTo to CCMoveBy and made it move the same distance, same duration, and now it's fine..  But it really should have worked the other way math-wise.

Comment: I often spend way too much time solving things like this when an alternative solution is easy, like you suggest. I hate not understanding why.